# Is the class of $k$-letter graphs finitely defined?

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I am completely bamboozled by this problem, and although I believe the answer 'should' be yes, I cannot prove it for love nor money! I'll provide a couple of definitions for clarity's sake.

> A $k$-*letter graph* $G$ is a graph defined by a finite word $x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n}$ over an alphabet $X$ of size $k$ together with a subset $S\subseteq{X^2}$ such that:
>
> - $V(G)$ = {$1,2,...,n$}
> - $E(G)$ = {$ij$ : $i\leq{j}$ and $(x_{i},x_{j})\in{S}$}

Note that $V(G)$ and $E(G)$ are the vertex-set and edge-set of $G$, and that $G$ is simple and undirected.

Also a hereditary class of graphs being *finitely defined* means that the set of minimal induced forbidden subgraphs for this class is finite.

I have a few ideas floating around, but not only are they hard to put into words, they don't appear to help. I spent all my energy trying to prove that the answer is yes, and have given little consideration to the possibility that the answer is no.

Many thanks.

Comment: If our word defining $G$ is $a,b,c,a,b,c$ then we have 6 vertices, one for each letter in the word and if say $(a,b)\in{S}$, then there is an edge between every $a$ and $b$ occurring in that order (so 3 edges)

Comment: Yes I take your point, it's the definition in the notes, and in order to make sense the  statement "$V(G)$ = {$x_{1},x_{2},...x_{n}$}" must allow for duplicates. I guess it's a different kind of set where {$a,c,b,a,b,c$} $\neq$ {$a,c,b$}. Not sure how to write that.

Comment: The definition of letter graphs in the original paper by Petkovsek has $V(G) = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with $E(G) = \{ij : x_{\min\{i,j\}}x_{\max\{i,j\}} \in S\}$, similar to bof's comment.

Comment: Ok I see now, and I've changed it. Still the question remains open.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that $G$ is a **directed** graph? With loops in case $(a,a)\in S$?

Comment: No $G$ is a simple undirected graph, if $(a,a)\in{S}$, then all vertices with the letter $a$ are pairwise adjacent (form a clique), but we don't allow loops. So if there is only one vertex with the letter $a$, it makes no difference whether $(a,a)\in{S}$ or $(a,a)\notin{S}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $H$ is a minimal forbidden induced subgraph for $k$-letter graphs. If we delete a vertex $v$, the result $H-v$ must be a $k$-letter graph; otherwise, $H-v$ would also be a forbidden induced subgraph, and $H$ would not be minimal.

We can use this to show that $H$ is a $(2k+1)$-letter graph. First, take a description of $H-v$ as a $k$-letter graph with alphabet $X$, word $x_1 x_2 \dots x_n$, and relation $S$. Define a new alphabet $X'$ which has two letters $x^+$ and $x^-$ for every $x \in S$, as well as one extra letter I'll just call $q$ for no reason.

For $i=1, \dots, n$, replace $x_i$ by $x_i^+$ if the $i^{\text{th}}$ vertex of $H-v$ is adjacent to $v$, and $x_i^-$ otherwise, getting a word over $X'$. Then, append $q$ to the end of this word. Define a new relation $S'$ with four pairs $(x^{\pm}, y^{\pm})$ for every pair $(x,y) \in S$, as well as the $k$ pairs $(x^+, q)$ for $x \in X$.  The resulting alphabet, word, and relation define $H$ as a letter graph.

---

So all minimal forbidden induced subgraphs are $(2k+1)$-letter graphs; now we will show that there are finitely many.

First of all, there are only finitely many relations $S$: only the piddling, insignificant amount of $2^{(2k+1)^2}$. (We assume a fixed alphabet $X$, since it doesn't really matter what the letters are called.) For each choice of $S$, if $H_1$ is a $(2k+1)$-letter graph defined by $S$, $X$, and a word $w$, and $H_2$ is a $(2k+1)$-letter graph defined by $S$, $x$, and a subword of $w$, then $H_2$ is an induced subgraph of $H_1$, so both of them cannot be minimal forbidden subgraphs.

But by [Higman's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_lemma), we can only pick finitely many words over $X$ without including a word and its subword. This means that for every relation $S$, there are finitely many minimal forbidden induced subgraphs defined with that relation.

Comment: Hi Misha, I'm completely with you until the last paragraph...

Comment: What is your question about the last paragraph?

Comment: "But by Higman's lemma, we can only pick finitely many words over $X$ without including a word and its subword" - I don't understand what you mean here. Are you saying that we can only form so many words over $X$ before our words start containing previous words as subwords?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. (Actually, our minimal forbidden subgraphs are unordered, and the sequence in Higman's lemma is ordered, so maybe a weaker result would do, but that's outside my area of expertise.)